# Boxplot across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, boxplot

all,

Pretty new to R so I'm having some trouble trying to figure this out. This is a sample of the data I'm working with...

| ID | Cross_specific | Cross_pop | seed_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | interspecific | NA | # |
| 2 | intraspecific | intrapopulation | # |
| 3 | intraspecific | interpopulation | # |

What I want to do is create a boxplot that separates the seed count by intraspecific/intrapopulation, intraspecific/interpopulation, and interspecific - so three separate boxplots. I'm pretty sure I'll have to get the boxplot to read across two different columns, which I think I've figured out.

The problem is it separates the boxplot into five categories: "interspecific" and "intraspecific" from the "Cross_specific" column as well as "NA", "intrapopulation", and "interpopulation" from the "Cross_pop_ column.

Is there a way to take the "intra" and "inter" categories (leaving the "NA" out) from the "Cross_pop" column and only the "interspecific" category from the "Cross_specific" column?

This is the line I used

```
boxplot(seed_count_avg~cross_pop+cross_specific="interspecific",data=data,main="Seed Count",xlab="Cross Type",ylab="Seed Count")
```

Unfortunately, I got an error (*Error: unexpected '=' in "boxplot(seed_count_avg~cross_pop+cross_specific="*, in case you're wondering).

I also used this code

```
boxplot(seed_count_avg~cross_pop+cross_specific,data=data,main="Seed Count",xlab="Cross Type",ylab="Seed Count")
```

Which created boxplots, but with empty spaces.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is "=interspecific" supposed to do? That is not a valid construct in `boxplot()`. What is `seed_count_avg`? That variable is not defined in your question. The value `NA` means missing data and many R functions will just ignore that which is probably not what you want. Actually that field is "not relevant" so it could be coded simply as "".  Provide some reproducible data using `dput(head(data, 20)` and paste the results into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be close to what you are trying to do. First we need reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
Cross_specific <- sample(c("interspecific", "intraspecific"), 100, replace=TRUE)
Cross_pop <- sample(c("intrapopulation", "interpopulation"), 100, replace=TRUE)
Cross_pop[Cross_specific=="interspecific"] <- ""
seed_count <- sample(1000, 100)
data <- data.frame(Cross_specific, Cross_pop, seed_count)
```

Whenever `Cross_specific=="interspecific"` we set the value of `Cross_pop` to "", not `NA` because this is not missing data. Now the boxplot:

```
boxplot(seed_count~Cross_specific+Cross_pop, data=data2, main="Seed Count", 
     xlab="Cross Type", ylab="Seed Count", drop=TRUE, cex.axis=.9)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! I took the NA's out and added the blanks, like you suggested - which seemed to help perfectly. Thank you!